# ESRI IdentityManager.registerToken unable to register Multiple servers

Tags: arcgis-10.1, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have multiple secured service that needs to be added to my map for which I need to register multiple servers using ESRi IdentityManager.registerToken method

```
      IdentityManager.registerToken({
            'server': "https://testurl1",
            'token': "abcasdasasd"
           });

           IdentityManager.registerToken({
            'server': "https://testurl2",
            'token': "MV5VF5SeK9pigO5094rC9MMEyY39SnmB"
           });
```

The First IdentityManager.registerToken for the testurl1 is able to register the token successfully but the  IdentityManager.registerToken for the testurl2 throws the following error

Cannot read property '3' of null
    at new k (init.js:457)
    at b.hasSameOrigin (init.js:731)
    at init.js:731
    at Object.some (init.js:70)
    at Object.b.canUseXhr (init.js:731)
    at Object. (init.js:1999)
    at Object.forEach (init.js:71)
    at Object.registerServers (init.js:1998)
    at Object.registerToken (init.js:1999)
    at Object.onReceiveData (Widget.js?wab_dv=2.10:48) "TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null
    at new k (https://js.arcgis.com/3.31/init.js:457:489)

Please provide some thoughts on how to fix this issue..

Thanks
Muthu

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to paas index here like testurl1/test url2 paas only main url without index

change
IdentityManager.registerToken({
'server': "https://testurl",
'token': "abcasdasasd"
});